# Cannot install any packages in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, aptitude

I am not able to install any packages into my system using apt. My system was perfect yesterday

Have a look please:

```
$ sudo apt-get install indicator-stickynotes
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libxrandr-ltsq2 libportaudio0 chromium-inspector lesstif2 xaw3dg
  libreadline5 libllvm3.1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python3 python3-gi python3-minimal python3.2 python3.2-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python3-doc python3-tk python3.2-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  indicator-stickynotes python3 python3-gi python3-minimal python3.2
  python3.2-minimal
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 455 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,522 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 syntax error: unknown user 'spread' in statoverride file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Whenever `dpkg` runs, it checks that all user-entries in the `/var/lib/dpkg/statoverride` file are in the `/etc/passwd`, and if all entries are not found, it issues a warning.

Thus, it seems that your system doesn't have the user `spread` anymore - either you (or some other admin) have removed the user or it has been removed along the removal of some program.

You can fix the situation either by

1. re-creating the missing user `spread` (or re-installing the program that creates the user)
2. removing the offending row(s) from `/var/lib/dpkg/statoverride`